# "НеперепитАя" - ято это значит?

Tags: семантика

добрый день. в детстве часто слышала от родни выражение "какая неперепитАя",означающее -какая необходимость.Например,Какая неперепитАя тебе туда ехать?хочу узнать,что означает это слово, и откуда пошло.Что за неперепитая, а может быть неперепетая? спасибо.

Comment: Вам бы для начала элементарные правила правописания выучить... Заголовок и метку поправил, остальное проще заново написать...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В общелитературном словнике этого слова нет. Что-то жаргонное или диалектное. 
"Перепитая" может означать "спившаяся". Если по этой линии идти, Возможно, что "неперепитая" - это "реальная", "насущная". "Насущная необходимость" - это вполне объясняет Ваши примеры.